# Get track information from Spotify API using ISRC code

Tags: spotify

Is it possible to get the track id (or better, the entire track metadata) using an ISRC code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can get information about a track given the ISRC using the [Search endpoint](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/search-item/).

For example, Metallica's Sad But True has the ISRC `USEE10001993`. A request to the Web API to retrieve the track metadata would be:

https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=track&q=isrc:USEE10001993

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Strange, the Spotify API docs I was reading was not this link...!

Comment: Do you know why you have to add a type=? ISRC is very specific (e.g. it couldn't match an album and song), so if I just have the ISRC code and not a type, would I need to run through every type= option until I got a hit? Thanks!

Comment: @Paul The ISRC always refers to a track. "ISRC codes are primarily used to identify and catalog individual songs (tracks) on an album." [source](https://www.isrcmusiccodes.com/general-faq.html#01)

Comment: HI, Any idea on how to get multiple tracks information by passing in multiple ISRC ids to the query param?