# Get multiple tracks from Spotify API using ISRC code

Tags: api, spotify, mediainfo

There is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35188813/get-track-information-from-spotify-api-using-isrc-code/50892063#50892063) to fetch a single track by querying the Spotify search API with ISRC.

But, I didn't find any way to fetch multiple tracks for the same.

I tried these ways but nothing worked:

Comma-separated: https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=track&q=isrc:USEE10001993,USEE10001994

Plus-separated: https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=track&q=isrc:USEE10001993+USEE10001994

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: can you show some code you are using?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting your question here. What code you're referring to here? It's purely a REST API call looking for a song matching the given ISRC in the query params?

Comment: I have no knowledge of how to make multiple calls with the syntax above. using a requests library and use a for loop should be a no brainer.

Comment: The question here is just because to avoid the for loop, as it isn't a convenient/reliable/scalable solution.

Comment: the way I see it, your solution does not seem convenient neither scalable, and not the other way around. it makes no sense to use multiple calls using your method.

Comment: It totally depends upon the requirements of the product you're building, could not be bluntly ignored. Still, don't agree?  ; FYI: Apple Music API's does provide this feature. Apple developers are not fools to provide this.

Comment: but this is Spotify API, not Apple Music API. and Spotify has a much more powerful API than Apple, apparently without this feature. How would you scale this request to, say, a hundred id requests, in one line? I don't see the point.

Comment: Before making any comments, please refer the API's & then talk on it, dude. No offense here.

Comment: well...before developing a product, you should do the same. no offense either.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, buddy. Have a good one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This request work fine for me: `https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?type=track&q=isrc:USWB11802164+OR+isrc:DEMA61301103`

Comment: Fantastic man! This is the one I was expecting. Is this documented somewhere? If so, can you please put that link here for reference? Thank you!

Comment: It just a combination "Field filters" and "search query operators".Documentation is here: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/search/search/

Comment: Does this method still work? For some reason I can't get it to output any songs when using the OR operator

Comment: Unfortunately, but this method does not work at this time. You can search ISCR code one by one only (not multiple).